# Differentiability of solution of optimization problem with respect to constraint (properties, conditions etc)

Tags: optimization, constraint, constraint-programming

Assume you have the following simple constrained optimization problem:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\min_x f(x) \\
& s.t \quad g(x) = c
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
where $f,g$ are both differentiable.

What are the standard way to show that the problem solution (here I am referring to the objective minimum, and not the decision variable) is/is not differentiable with respect to $c$? I have run a few concrete examples and found that numerically the solution seems to be differentiable, but I have no idea how to show it more formally.

Comment: What do you mean by: "solution is/is not differentiable with respect to $c$"?

Comment: Note that " $f,g$ are both differentiable for a given $c$" should be "$f,g$ are both differentiable" since neither depends on $c.$

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade i mean the objective minimum (i.e solution of the problem; note that I am not referring to the decision variable here) of this optimization problem would change w.r.t $c$, thus one can also define a certain notion of differentiability for the minimum with respect to $c$.

Comment: @prubin thanks for pointing it out, i edited that phrase away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rich literature on parametric optimization, which deals with questions of when the optimal value/solution of an optimization problem is (sub)differentiable with respect to its parameters.

Classical references are:

1. Fiacco's book "Introduction to Sensitivity and Stability Analysis in Nonlinear Programming", available for purchase [here](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/introduction-to-sensitivity-and-stability-analysis-in-nonlinear-programming/fiacco/978-0-12-254450-7)
2. Bonnans and Shapiro's book "Perturbation Analysis of Optimization Problems", available for download/purchase [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1394-9)

A more approachable reference is:

1. Still's "Lectures on Parametric Optimization: An Introduction", which can be downloaded for free [here](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/6587.pdf)

In particular, Theorem 4.4 in Still's lecture notes provides general conditions under which the optimal value function of your problem is differentiable with respect to the parameter $c$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the optimization problem you have stated may not have a unique optimum, i.e, there may exist multiple optimal solutions.
Consider, for instance, $\min_{x,y} \{ x | x=c, 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$: any solution $(c,y)$ is optimal.

In that case, the mapping from $c$ to an optimal solution of the problem is one-to-many, and is therefore not differentiable.
This is often the case when $f$ and/or $g$ are non-convex: the optimum may not be unique, or it may jump to a distant point even under small perturbation.

There is a rich literature in the machine learning community on differentiating through an optimization problem.
As far as I know, they all rely (in some form or the other) on the KKT conditions. One of the most famous paper is
[this NeurIPS 2019 paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/hash/9ce3c52fc54362e22053399d3181c638-Abstract.html) for the convex case.

Comment: Sorry, but i am actually referring to the objective minimum (not the decision variable) of the optimization problem. Thus the issue of one-to-many seems to not be an issue right?